# How to load RTF and HTML into Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, report

Crystal report not support RTF big size, i thinks crystal report limit the message, please suggestion with me how to fix it ? or i should be change to SQL Reporting Services ?

Please help me.

Relate issue (see last comment):

- [http://vbcity.com/forums/p/104797/709343.aspx#709343]
- [http://vbcity.com/forums/t/152980.aspx]

Thanks, 
Utehn

---

> Now the problem are resoled, Thank Benz

```
    Dim tblData As New DataTable()
    tblData.Columns.Add("Display", GetType(String))

    Dim dr As DataRow = tblData.NewRow()
    'dr(0) = RichTextBox1.Rtf
    RichTextBox1.LoadFile("test2.rtf")
    dr(0) = RichTextBox1.Rtf

    tblData.Rows.Add(dr)

    Dim report1 As New CrystalReport1()
    report1.SetDataSource(tblData)

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report1
```

Comment: Utehn, unless Benz confirms he's okay with it - you might want to remove his email from your post. It can be read and added to spam lists since it's just there in plain text to be read by email collecting scripts. It would also be kind of you to add the answer he gave to this question and mark it as the answer. This allows others with the same issue to also get help. Thanks!

Comment: Removed email, Thanks for your comment and advise.